# Start all automatic services not running

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to further automate our Windows patching to automatically attempt to start any services that are set to Auto but are not running.

Below is what I've tried so far with no success:

```
$stoppedServices = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'" | select name

foreach ($stoppedService in $stoppedServices) {
  Set-Service -Service $stoppedService -Status Running
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Set-Service : Service @{name=RemoteRegistry} was not found on computer '.'.
At line:4 char:13
+             Set-Service -Service $stoppedService -Status Running
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.:String) [Set-Service], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'd suggest the following if you need only a simple one-liner:


     Get-WMIObject win32_service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'" | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name StartService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Adrian R's suggestion and it works great. Here's the final version:

`#Start all non-running Auto services
Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running' AND name != 'sppsvc'" | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name StartService
 #Output any services still not running
$stoppedServices = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running' AND name != 'sppsvc'" | select -expand Name
Write-Host "$env:ComputerName : Stopped Services: $stoppedServices"`

FYI if you don't exclude the SPPSVC you'll get the below error:
`Set-Service : Service 'Software Protection (sppsvc)' cannot be configured due to the following error: Access is denied`

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parameter `-Expand`, otherwise you still have an object with a property `Name` instead of the value of that property:

```
$stoppedServices = Get-WmiObject win32_service ... | select -Expand name
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-ExpandProperty` option will work. You can also use the following example:

```
$stoppedServices = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'" | foreach {$_.Name}
```

Piping the results into foreach will provide you with a stream of values.

Ref: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/09/14/select-expandproperty-propertyname.aspx